# How to write a collection of static variable in Rust

Tags: rust, enums, static-variables

I want to collect the static variable like java

```java
Class A {
  public static final String HELLO = "hello";
  public static final String WORLD = "world";
}
```

But it's not supported by enum or struct in Rust!
Should I use something like `static HashMap`?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What it is exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most literal and straightforward conversion of this would be "associated constants":

```
struct A { /* .. */ }

impl A {
    const HELLO: &str = "hello";
    const WORLD: &str = "world";
}
```

which would be accessible via `A::HELLO` and `A::WORLD`.

---

However, if you don't intend on using `A` and just wanted it as a scoping mechanism, you should use a module:

```
mod constants {
    const HELLO: &str = "hello";
    const WORLD: &str = "world";
}
```

which would be accessible via `constants::HELLO` and `constants::WORLD`.

---

If you wanted this as a static hash map, that would look like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.15.0

static A: Lazy<HashMap<&str, &str>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("HELLO", "hello");
    map.insert("WORLD", "world");
    map
});
```

In Rust, `static` variables must be initialized with a `const` expression, but since inserting into a `HashMap` is not `const`, we can use `Lazy` from the once-cell crate to initialize it lazily. This will obviously be different to access since it is not a set of known definitions: `A.get("HELLO").unwrap()`